# Usage Of "Override"

Tags: word-meaning, phrasal-verbs

The verb "override" is a transitive verb.  It is followed by an object.  But, does it mean "to stop the action of a (machine/mechanism) " or "to stop a (machine's/mechanism's) action"?  In another word, would the object of "override" be the action or the machine?  Assuming below that the operator is a human and the controller is a machine:

1. "The operator overrode the shutdown controller."
2. "The operator overrode the shutdown."

Most dictionaries suggest that the machine should be the object.  But this dictionary entry [(def 3)](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/override)  suggests that the action could also be the object for "override".

Comment: This is interesting. I believe that both of your alternatives are possible. However, if I were to write it, I'd write it as *"The operator overrode the shutdown process."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They amount to the same thing.

The base sense of *override* means to cancel or withdraw a **command**. But when you cancel a **command** you are also doing two other things: you are preventing the commanded **action** from being performed, and you are abrogating the authority of the **agent** who issued the command. It is thus a perfectly natural extension of the base sense to say that you *override* the act and that you *override* the agent.

Looking at the examples in your dictionary:

1. When Congress overrides the President's veto (command) it is also overriding the prohibition (action) of the law and the authority of the President (agent) to issue that prohibition.
2. When you “let anger override common sense”, you are allowing your anger to abrogate the authority of common sense (agent) to determine (command) your behavior (action).
3. When you “enter a code to override the alarm” you are also abrogating the authority of the system (agent) which to issue (command) the alarm (action).

So by the same token, when you *override* the shutdown controller (agent) you prevent it from initiating (commanding) the shutdown process (action).

- override the controller ...
- override the shutdown order ...
- override the shutdown ...

They're all valid.

Comment: +1 but I think of the base sense of override as more of *supercede* than *cancel*  If I override something I am in effect saying, "I don't care what your orders might have been, I am a higher authority and I'm telling you to do X!"

Comment: According to Collins definition sense 4 "to disregard, overrule, or nullify; specif., to change or cancel (an automatic function)" so it could be cancel or change, but cancel would happen first. Change or do nothing then would be the options.

Comment: When I play Crisis 2 (a FPS sci-fi PC game), the soldier wears a nanosuit. Its visor sometimes says "system overrides". At that time I cannot switch any combat modes (bullet-proof, cloak, fast-moving, power) of the suit. Does it mean "system overrides the manual control"? @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng I don't know the game, but a little Googling suggests that is exactly the case: the system automatically overrides your manual settings when it detects specific threats.